# Google maps embed, will results always be the same?

Tags: google-maps-embed

I have a question about using the google maps embed api. When using this api with the following code:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={KEY}&q=Leeuwarden
```

Will the result for users always be the same? (note key will always be the same). Or will the result depend on the users (viewer) location? For example if a location with the same name exists multiple times.